# How to get a chat room owner in quickblox?

Tags: quickblox

i want to retrieve that info for can handle the way of the users can view or join to the chat rooms.

i've tried many differents ways, but i can't find how quickblox assign or sets the owner.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve chat owners only if you one of them too.